# how to copy or cut a file for nautilus using qclipboard

Tags: python, qml, pyqt5, qclipboard

I want to copy a file to nautilus using Qclipboard. This is what I made

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
data = QtCore.QMimeData()
url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('/home/newtron/test/main.qml')
data.setUrls([url])

QApplication.clipboard().setMimeData(data)
```

But the URL copied as a link not as a file. What do I need to do to set clipboard data as a file.

using gnome and linux.

Comment: Explain yourself better I do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you didn't set mime type needed for `QClipboard`. For example, in GNOME this is `x-special/gnome-copied-files`. When using `QMimeData` check out this page https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#setData for C++, or this for Python https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QMimeData.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QMimeData.setData .

So you need to include it in your code:

`PySide2.QtCore.QMimeData.setData(mimetype, data)`

Where `mimetype` is `x-special/gnome-copied-files`, or else which can be recognized by file manager.

Comment: Son what I can do for move function

Comment: how to set data?